# How To Check If Image Uploaded? AJAX PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to develop a web app where you are allowed to create posts and have an (just one) image with it, but you don't have to have one it could also be just a text post. This is only a personal project to try and get better with php and ajax so I may be doing this wrong... What I am trying to do is on submit send the form data to a php function that will determine whether to upload it or not, then what I want to do is if it is successful send the image name to a different function to insert the post into the database, but if the image upload is not successful display the errors. Also if is it not successful but the error is 'No image uploaded', go ahead and create the post anyway.

Here is what I have so far

The jQuery

```
   $(".new-post").submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "includes/image-upload.php",
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var body = $("#post-body").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "create-post-feed.php",
                data: {
                    body: body,
                    image: response
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    //                        console.log(response);
                    $('section.feed').prepend(response);
                    $('article.post p').each(function () {
                        $(this).html(linkHashtags($(this).html()));
                    });
                    $('article.post p').each(function () {
                        $(this).html(linkatsymbols($(this).html()));
                    });
                    revealPosts();
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

The PHP
After some research I found out that if it is an error I have to send it back as JSON and then check the results in jQuery. However I have yet to get that working...

```
<?php

require_once('../dbconnect.php');
include_once( INCLUDES_PATH .'functions.php');

function uploadFile ($file_field = null, $check_image = false, $random_name = false) {

//Config Section 
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//check if directory exist if not create it
if (!file_exists(HOME_PATH ."users/user_".$user_id)) {
    mkdir(HOME_PATH ."users/user_".$user_id, 0777, true);
}
if (!file_exists(HOME_PATH ."users/user_".$user_id."/posts")) {
    mkdir(HOME_PATH ."users/user_".$user_id."/posts", 0777, true);
}
//Set file upload path
$path = "../users/user_".$user_id."/posts/"; //with trailing slash
//Set max file size in bytes
$max_size = 1000000;
//Set default file extension whitelist
$whitelist_ext = array('jpeg','jpg','png','gif');
//Set default file type whitelist
$whitelist_type = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png','image/gif');

//The Validation
// Create an array to hold any output
$out = array('error'=>null);

if (!$file_field) {
    $out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid form field name";           
}

if (!$path) {
    $out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid upload path";               
}

if (count($out['error'])>0) {
    return $out;
}

//Make sure that there is a file
if((!empty($_FILES[$file_field])) && ($_FILES[$file_field]['error'] == 0)) {

    // Get filename
    $file_info = pathinfo($_FILES[$file_field]['name']);
    $name = $file_info['filename'];
    $ext = $file_info['extension'];

    //Check file has the right extension           
    if (!in_array($ext, $whitelist_ext)) {
        $out['error'][] = "Invalid file Extension";
    }

    //Check that the file is of the right type
    if (!in_array($_FILES[$file_field]["type"], $whitelist_type)) {
        $out['error'][] = "Invalid file Type";
    }

    //Check that the file is not too big
    if ($_FILES[$file_field]["size"] > $max_size) {
        $out['error'][] = "File is too big";
    }

    //If $check image is set as true
    if ($check_image) {
        if (!getimagesize($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'])) {
            $out['error'][] = "Uploaded file is not a valid image";
        }
    }

    //Create full filename including path
    if ($random_name) {
        // Generate random filename
        $tmp = str_replace(array('.',' '), array('',''), microtime());

    if (!$tmp || $tmp == '') {
        $out['error'][] = "File must have a name";
    }     
        $newname = $tmp.'.'.$ext;                                
    } else {
        $newname = $name.'.'.$ext;
    }

    //Check if file already exists on server
    if (file_exists($path.$newname)) {
        $out['error'][] = "A file with this name already exists";
    }

    if (count($out['error'])>0) {
        //The file has not correctly validated
        return $out;
    } 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'], $path.$newname)) {
        echo $newname;
    } else {
        $out['error'][] = "Server Error!";
    }
 } else {
    $out['error'][] = "No file uploaded";
    return $out;
 }      
}

$file = uploadFile('file', true, true);

if (is_array($file['error'])) {
echo json_encode($file['error']);
}

die();
```

Really appreciate any help or comments on how to make it better
BTW This currently works, the only problem is that the post is always created whether the image uploaded or not.

Usually i would at least get an answer on the same day... Is this question that bad? XD I heard editing will help 'bump the question up'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you said you want to do is different than what you actually did. In your code, you are attempting two AJAX calls: (1) upload the image and (2) save the post.

Why not do both things at once in one call? This way you don't have to wait for the response of uploading the image (or none) to create a new post.

```
$(".new-post").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "create-post-feed.php",
        data: new FormData(this), // send post information including selected file
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        success: function (response) {
            // etc
        }
    });
});
```

Then in your `create-post-feed.php`, merge the logic you have in `image-upload.php` with the current code. I typically do it like this:

```
// validate post

// validate image (if any)

// if no errors:

    // upload image (if any) and retrieve filename

// if no errors:

    // save post (with filename if any); if it fails, delete image (if any)

// send response
```

Comment: Ohhhh I see wow I was making things over complicated... Hmm alright I'll try that thanks!

Comment: Wait how would I retrieve the body contents from the FormData() in php? @Mikey

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve the data you submitted with AJAX? The same way you normally do it by looking at `$_POST` and `$_FILES` arrays. Ensure that all your inputs within your form have `name` attributes.